# Git workflow that allow new hire to work on feature without polluting git history

Tags: git, gitflow

We want a new hire to work on some features of our current project, however, since he is a new hire, we would like to do code review before he can commit into master branch. Also, we don't want his changes which is rejected by our code review and get into the history.

What would be the ideal git workflow for this? 
(I think is quite common?)

Comment: Let him clone and submit pull requests.  You can see his stuff before you accept his stuff.

Comment: I will just point out, these practices have merit for all members of your team, not just new hires.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do to ensure a clean Git history.  There may be a faster way to achieve the same thing with fewer commands.  In summary:

- Create a feature branch;
- Work on the branch;
- Review the branch;
- Squash the feature into a single commit (note that this is not a great plan unless the scope of the feature is small);
- Rebase the feature onto the main branch (to ensure a linear history);
- Perform a fast-forward merge.

Different folks will argue that squashing commits is bad; this works for me.  Do whatever works for you.

Start a new branch for the feature:

```
git checkout -b some_user/some_feature
```

Write some code.

Add changes to the branch:

```
git add .
git commit -m "I did some stuff."
```

Write some code.

Add changes to the branch:

```
git add .
git commit -m "I did some more stuff."
```

Review the changes.

Update master:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Switch back to the feature branch:

```
git checkout some_user/some_feature
```

Squash the feature's commits into a single commit:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Rebase the commit onto master to ensure that the merge will be a fast-forward:

```
git rebase master
```

Deal with any merge conflicts.

Merge the feature into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge some_user/some_feature
```

Push to the server:

```
git push origin master
```

Get rid of the feature branch:

```
git branch -d some_user/some_feature
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the advantages and disadvantages of squashing commits, rather than just saying that people disagree.

Answer (score 0):

> We want a new hire to work on some features of our current project, however, since he is a new hire, we would like to do code review before he can commit into master branch.

Create a separate feature branch (or several, if this person will be working on multiple unrelated features) with the [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command.  Periodically [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) from `master` into the feature branch(es) (that is, run `git merge master` while standing on the feature branch).  Once you've reviewed the code, merge the feature branch(es) into `master` (run `git merge feature` while standing on `master`).

Some people will tell you to use [rebases](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) instead of merges in some or all cases.  A rebase turns your history into a straight line, so that this:

```
A ----> B
 \
  \
   ---> C
```

...becomes this (C is rebased onto B, creating C'):

```
A ----> B ----> C'
```

...rather than this (C is merged with B, creating D):

```
A ----> B -----> D
 \            /
  \          /
   ---> C ---
```

Rebased history is easier to read and (marginally) easier to [bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect), but may provide a less accurate picture of how your code was developed, which might make it harder to reason about what actually happened.  Rebasing is also more complicated if the commit you are rebasing (C in our example) has already been pushed or pulled into another repository, while merging does not have this issue.  Ultimately, you will need to decide for yourself which is the more appropriate course of action for your use case.

> Also, we don't want his changes which is rejected by our code review and get into the history.

Delete the branch (with `git branch -D feature`) without merging it into `master`, and wait for Git to [garbage collect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) the orphaned commits automatically.  Note the changes are gone for good after that, so be very sure you no longer want to keep them before running this command.

If you accidentally delete the wrong branch *and notice the problem immediately* (or soon after), you can recover it [from the reflog](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery).

Comment: >> Delete the branch without merging it into master, and wait for Git to garbage collect the orphaned commits automatically.
How? Can you explain more?

Comment: @Yoga: Added sample command.

Comment: I'm downvoting because your suggestions will *guarantee* that the commit history gets polluted with minor commits. The correct solution here is to rebase when pulling from master into feature, and to rebase/squash feature into a single commit prior to merging feature into master.

Comment: @RubberDuck: My answer already explains the advantages *and drawbacks* of that approach.  I have no intention of altering it to pick a "right" side.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't DV because I disagree with you. I might, I might not. I downvoted because your answer runs in direct opposition to the goals OP is trying to achieve. It's not personal, so please don't take it personally.

Comment: @RubberDuck: I disagree.  OP wants to drop history for rejected code, not all code.